# How to get text of this html element while preserving some inner tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup and have found an element in my document like so:

```
<p><a id="_Toc374204393"></a><a id="_Toc374204469"></a>Hershey's<sup>®</sup> makes yummy chocolate</p>
```

and I'd like to extract

```
Hershey's<sup>®</sup> makes yummy chocolate
```

I know I can take this item and grab its `.contents`, and then re-join the text if it doesn't include an `<a>`, but that seems like a super hacky way to do it. How else might I get this text? Using methods like `get_text()` return me the text but without the `<sup>` tags which I'd like to preserve.

Comment: How did you go ahead doing the `.contents` approach? is my provided answer better than that?

Comment: `.contents` would give me something like `[a id="_Toc374204393"></a>,<a id="_Toc374204469"></a>,"Hershey's",<sup>®</sup>, "makes yummy chocolate"]`, from which I can just iterate over and drop the a tags in some way or another. I suppose it's a fine answer, but just seems like there might be a method to do what I want. Maybe there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`next_siblings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p><a id="_Toc374204393"></a><a id="_Toc374204469"></a>Hershey's<sup>®</sup> makes yummy chocolate</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(
    "".join(str(x) for x in soup.find("a", id="_Toc374204469").next_siblings)
)
```

Output:

```
Hershey's<sup>®</sup> makes yummy chocolate
```

Comment: This works for this particular case, but is not ideal because I have other strings without this `id` attribute to key on so it won't work in general.

Comment: @gammapoint Does `"".join(str(x) for x in soup.select_one("a:last-of-type").next_siblings)` work?

Comment: Thanks, Mendel. That might also work, but I'm not sure it's better than the approach with `bleach` I just found and posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found thusfar is to use the `bleach` package. With that, I can just do

```
import bleach
bleach.clean(my_html, tags=['sup'], strip=True)
```

This wasn't working for me at first because my html was a BeautifulSoup `Tag` object, and bleach wants the html. So I just did `str(Tag)` to get the html representation and fed that to bleach.